# New to MySQL and i'm stuck on a SAKILA exercise

Tags: mysql, sql

I started learning SQL a month ago and i found this SAKILA homework and thought i should try it, to test myself. I'm a bit stuck on an exercise and i don't know what i'm doing wrong. Can someone help me?

The problem is:

> Find the names (first and last) of all the actors and costumers whose first name is the same as the first name of the actor with ID 8. Do not return the actor with ID 8 himself. Note that you cannot use the name of the actor with ID 8 as a constant (only the ID). There is more than one way to solve this question, but you need to provide only one solution.

My code is:

1.

```
SELECT customer.first_name,customer.last_name FROM customer

LEFT JOIN actor ON (customer.first_name LIKE actor_id=8) 
            AND (actor.first_name LIKE actor_id=8)
```

2.

```
SELECT customer.first_name,customer.last_name FROM customer

LEFT JOIN actor ON customer_id=actor_id

WHERE (customer.first_name LIKE actor_id=8) AND (actor.first_name LIKE actor_id=8)
```

I get a lot of names returned but none of them are the correct ones. What am i doing wrong? Why is the code not returning the same name as the actor's who's Id is 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the actors as well as customer names. Both are in two different tables; hence one way can be to use `UNION ALL`.

```
(SELECT customer_id AS id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name
 FROM customer
 WHERE first_name = (SELECT first_name FROM actor WHERE actor_id = 8))

UNION ALL

(SELECT actor_id AS id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name
 FROM actor
 WHERE actor_id <> 8 AND 
       first_name = (SELECT first_name FROM actor WHERE actor_id = 8))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I didn't think to use the UNION and i kept trying resolving it with JOINS

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to combine the names from actors and costumers we'll do that first with the UNION. Then that result set is joined with the actor 8 to match the firstname.

```
SELECT s.first_name,s.last_name 
FROM (
  SELECT c.first_name,c.last_name 
  FROM customer c
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.first_name,a.last_name 
  FROM actor a
  WHERE a.actor_id != 8
) as s
  JOIN actor a8 ON a8.first_name = s.first_name
WHERE a8.actor_id=8
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It returns the correct names

Answer (score -1):

I would say

```
Select C.firstName, C.lastName 
from Customer C, actor A 
where C.firstName=A.firstName and C.lastName=A.lastName and A.id=8
```

This means, you are searching in the database for all the records in the "customer" table where the first and last name are exactly the same as the one in the record with id 8 of the table Actor. You use "and" because you want all the conditions to be true at the same time. You don't extract anything from actors because you don't need it: it is the "select" that does internally; anyway, you should also extract other significant data from customer, otherwise you will only get a bunch of all identical rows.

Query n°2:

```
Select A.fistName, A.lastName 
from actor A 
where A.firstName=(
  select firstName 
  from actor where id=8
) and A.lastName=(
  select lastName 
  from actor where id=8
) and id<>8
```

You must use subqueries, i.e. the "select" between (); that because if you search for id=8 in the table actor you will only get one row, the one with id=8. With subqueries the db first gets the data you to use for the comparison and only then searches for the other rows.

Comment: I would say this could do with a bit of exposition.